# ChartJS tooltip delay

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am using **ChartJS** (version 2.1.4) for a budget control application to display a line chart tracking monthly spend against budget.

When the user hovers over a point on the line chart, I am using the **callbacks - label** function within the **options - tooltips** configuration to display a form showing the transaction detail making up the monthly spend value.

However, I don't want the form to be activated unless the user hovers over the graph point for 3 seconds or more but I can't work out how to apply a delay to the tooltips configuration. My understanding is that the hover tooltip delay may be configured by setting the  **hover - animationDuration** value but I have tried this without success. How do I do this?